# insert fail access to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, oledb

I'm trying to insert some value into SQL Server from an Access databbase but it fails because of datetime column which named colz. In SQL Server I have a datetime column(colz) and in access it is datetime too (row["c"]).

There are no wrongs with datatypes and connections. No problem with dates like 1.mm.yyyy. The problem is with the dates like 10 to 31.mm.yyyy. Exception says

> The conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

When I try with the operand # exception says

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

My code with # was like  '#"......."#'

```
int i, k = dt.Rows.Count;
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    insertToSql = insertToSql + "insert into myTable(colx,coly,colz) values('"
        + dt.Rows[i]["a"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
        + dt.Rows[i]["b"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
        + dt.Rows[i]["c"].ToString().Trim() + "')";
}
```

Comment: Maybe write your `insertToSql` string to a log file somewhere before you run it, so you can look through it for errors.

Comment: That's why you use parameters.

Comment: Did you strip out the #. You need it in access

Comment: I have used breakpoints.it raises when the command finished.dates like 10 to 31.mm.yyyy throws error.It already inserts dates  when day between 1-9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

You should *never* store your `DateTime` values as a string. If your `dt.Rows[i]["c"]` *already* a `DateTime`, you should explicitly cast them to `DateTime` and send them exactly with [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) with `OleDbType.Date` parameter type.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable(colx,coly,colz) values(?, ?, ?)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["a"].ToString().Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["b"].ToString().Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["c"];

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Comment: I dont store datetime as a string.In select query I used breakpoints and saw it comes datetime.but in command it fails with 10-31 days.

Comment: it workes successfull.Thanks Soner.In for iteration I have written like your code and no problem with parameters.Only changed "OleDbType" to "SqlDbType" and it's equals

Answer (score 1):

You need to format date fields in YYYY-MM-DD for consistency.  The date parser is confusing month and day values when the month number is 10 or higher.

10-12-2016 may throw an error, whereas 2016-10-12 will not.

Comment: in my sql column it is already formatted like 2016-10-12 00:00:00.000 you mean access column?